# Detail Page Link open in same window in lightning

Tags: lightning, formula, custom-link

I have a requirement to have Back button, which should navigate to the related record. Basically, it works like lookup field but has custom text. The problem is that it always open in new tab, even when I set the Behavior to Display in existing window. I used this formula on the link:

```
one.app#/sObject/{!Object_A__c.Related_Object_ID__c}/view
```

Any suggestions how can I open this in the same tab, ideally without refreshing whole page?

Comment: Is it a custom formula field of type hyperlink on standard page layout opening parent record?

Comment: It is Custom Button or Link Detail, type Detail Page Link with formula as Link URL